# Did the Buddha make any reference to Krishna and Gita?

Tags: karma, the-buddha, texts, hinduism

As Hinduism was a prominent religion of the Buddha's time (though not in today's unified form ), Buddha must have learnt about the Gita and krishna's philosophy. In fact, the Buddha's karma philosophy and the notion of 'skillful karma' ( performing actions as duty without getting attached to it) seem to be too close to Krishna's karma yoga philosophy to find any difference.

Is there any reference to the Gita or Krishna in Buddhist texts?

Answer (score 4):

The dates given in Wikipedia's [Bhagavad Gita](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bhagavad_Gita) article, for example,

> Professor Jeaneane Fowler, in her commentary on the Gita, considers second century BCE to be the likely date of composition.

... and,

> The so-called "Hindu Synthesis" emerged during the early Classical period (200 BCE - 300 CE) of Hinduism.[21][7][22] According to Alf Hiltebeitel, a period of consolidation in the development of Hinduism took place between the time of the late Vedic Upanishad (ca. 500 BCE) and the period of the rise of the Guptas (ca. 320–467 CE) which he calls the "Hindu Synthesis", "Brahmanic Synthesis", or "Orthodox Synthesis".[21] It developed in interaction with other religions and peoples:
>
> > The emerging self-definitions of Hinduism were forged in the context of continuous interaction with heterodox religions (Buddhists, Jains, Ajivikas) throughout this whole period, and with foreign people (Yavanas, or Greeks; Sakas, or Scythians; Pahlavas, or Parthians; and Kusanas, or Kushans) from the third phase on [between the Mauryan empire and the rise of the Guptas].

... and in Wikipedia's [Krishna](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Krishna) article,

> Worship of the deity Krishna, either in the form of deity Krishna or in the form of Vasudeva, Bala Krishna or Gopala can be traced to as early as the 4th century BC.

... compared with the dates in the [Gautama Buddha](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gautama_Buddha) article,

> The times of Gautama's birth and death are uncertain. Most historians in the early 20th century dated his lifetime as circa 563 BCE to 483 BCE.

... suggest to me it's possible that maybe the Buddha lived a little bit earlier (e.g. 100 years or more) than when Krishna became famous and when the Gita was composed.

If it's true that the Gita was written during a "synthesis" which occurred as a reaction to competition from Buddhism and Jainism and so on, that could explain why there's no commentary from the Buddha (i.e. that he lived slightly before then, and so any commentary would be anachronistic).

There are Buddhist suttas which recount the Buddha's talking with brahmins.

In summary the first sentence of the OP (i.e. "As Hinduism was a prominent religion of the Buddha's time (though not in today's unified form), Buddha must have learnt about the Gita and krishna's philosophy.") might be a slightly incorrect assumption.

Comment: Krishna was famous before Buddha. Mahābhārata whose hero is Krishna dates back to before Buddha but in it Krishna was mostly a war strategist. Bhagavad Gita might have been written down much after the time of Buddha to disseminate the messages of the Upanishads to the larger public.

Comment: @ChrisW Thank you for the detailed response.

Answer (score 3):

> In fact, the Buddha's karma philosophy and the notion of 'skillful karma' ( performing actions as duty without getting attached to it) seem to be too close to Krishna's karma yoga philosophy to find any difference.

The Buddhist skillful Karma is not to do any action as a duty without attachment but to perform action with volitions which contain the roots of non aversion, non craving and non ignorance.

In Buddhis volition is the forerunner of Karma. If the volition is good, i.e., roots of non aversion, non craving and non ignorance, then the results would be also good.

> Is there any reference to the Gita or Krishna in Buddhist texts?

I don't think there are.

Comment: Could you please elaborate the answer on the first point?

Comment: Brilliantly expounded.

Answer (score 0):

> **OP:** Is there any reference to the Gita or Krishna in Buddhist texts?

No. Only the three Vedas (presumably Rg, Yajur and Sama Veda) are mentioned in Buddhist texts (see [MN 95](https://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/mn/mn.095x.than.html)). No other Hindu texts are mentioned.

> **OP:** In fact, the Buddha's karma philosophy and the notion of 'skillful
> karma' ( performing actions as duty without getting attached to it)
> seem to be too close to Krishna's karma yoga philosophy to find any
> difference.

TL;DR:

Actually, the two are very different.

Krishna taught to perform your duty and do not be attached to the fruit of actions. So, if your duty is as a warrior, then you should fight the battle but not be attached to the fruit of actions i.e. victory or loss.

The Buddha taught that intention (or volition) is the most important element of karma. It's impossible to fight in battle without having one's intention or volition tainted with aversion and delusion. Please see [this answer](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/a/26411/471).

Detailed quotes:

What did Lord Krishna teach?

From [Bhagavad Gita 2.31-38](https://www.holy-bhagavad-gita.org/chapter/2):

> Besides, considering your duty as a warrior, you should not waver.
> Indeed, for a warrior, there is no better engagement than fighting for
> upholding of righteousness. O Parth, happy are the warriors to whom
> such opportunities to defend righteousness come unsought, opening for
> them the stairway to the celestial abodes. If, however, you refuse to
> fight this righteous war, abandoning your social duty and reputation,
> you will certainly incur sin. People will speak of you as a coward and
> a deserter. For a respectable person, infamy is worse than death. The
> great generals who hold you in high esteem will think that you fled
> from the battlefield out of fear, and thus will lose their respect for
> you. Your enemies will defame and humiliate you with unkind words,
> disparaging your might. Alas, what could be more painful than that? If
> you fight, you will either be slain on the battlefield and go to the
> celestial abodes, or you will gain victory and enjoy the kingdom on
> earth. Therefore arise with determination, O son of Kunti, and be
> prepared to fight. Fight for the sake of duty, treating alike
> happiness and distress, loss and gain, victory and defeat. Fulfilling
> your responsibility in this way, you will never incur sin.

And what did the Buddha teach?

From [Yodhajiva Sutta (SN 42.3)](https://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/sn/sn42/sn42.003.than.html):

> Then Yodhajiva the headman went to the Blessed One and, on arrival,
> having bowed down to him, sat to one side. As he was sitting there he
> said to the Blessed One: "Lord, I have heard that it has been passed
> down by the ancient teaching lineage of warriors that 'When a warrior
> strives & exerts himself in battle, if others then strike him down &
> slay him while he is striving & exerting himself in battle, then with
> the breakup of the body, after death, he is reborn in the company of
> devas slain in battle.' What does the Blessed One have to say about
> that?"
>
> "Enough, headman, put that aside. Don't ask me that."
>
> A second time... A third time Yodhajiva the headman said: "Lord, I
> have heard that it has been passed down by the ancient teaching
> lineage of warriors that 'When a warrior strives & exerts himself in
> battle, if others then strike him down & slay him while he is striving
> & exerting himself in battle, then with the breakup of the body, after
> death, he is reborn in the company of devas slain in battle.' What
> does the Blessed One have to say about that?"
>
> "Apparently, headman, I haven't been able to get past you by saying,
> 'Enough, headman, put that aside. Don't ask me that.' So I will simply
> answer you. When a warrior strives & exerts himself in battle, his
> mind is already seized, debased, & misdirected by the thought: 'May
> these beings be struck down or slaughtered or annihilated or
> destroyed. May they not exist.' If others then strike him down & slay
> him while he is thus striving & exerting himself in battle, then with
> the breakup of the body, after death, he is reborn in the hell called
> the realm of those slain in battle. But if he holds such a view as
> this: 'When a warrior strives & exerts himself in battle, if others
> then strike him down & slay him while he is striving & exerting
> himself in battle, then with the breakup of the body, after death, he
> is reborn in the company of devas slain in battle,' that is his wrong
> view. Now, there are two destinations for a person with wrong view, I
> tell you: either hell or the animal womb."
>
> When this was said, Yodhajiva the headman sobbed & burst into tears.
> [The Blessed One said:] "That is what I couldn't get past you by
> saying, 'Enough, headman, put that aside. Don't ask me that.'"
>
> "I'm not crying, lord, because of what the Blessed One said to me, but
> simply because I have been deceived, cheated, & fooled for a long time
> by that ancient teaching lineage of warriors who said: 'When a warrior
> strives & exerts himself in battle, if others then strike him down &
> slay him while he is striving & exerting himself in battle, then with
> the breakup of the body, after death, he is reborn in the company of
> devas slain in battle.'
>
> "Magnificent, lord! Magnificent! Just as if he were to place upright
> what was overturned, to reveal what was hidden, to show the way to one
> who was lost, or to carry a lamp into the dark so that those with eyes
> could see forms, in the same way has the Blessed One — through many
> lines of reasoning — made the Dhamma clear. I go to the Blessed One
> for refuge, to the Dhamma, and to the Community of monks. May the
> Blessed One remember me as a lay follower who has gone to him for
> refuge, from this day forward, for life."

Answer (score -1):

there is [this](https://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/kn/snp/snp.3.02.irel.html) sutta...

the footnote says:

The "Dark One" or Kanha (Sanskrit: Krishna), is another name for Mara. He is the Indian Cupid (Kamadeva) and personifies sensual passions

Also in [this](https://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/dn/dn.20.0.piya.html#fnt-s18-15) sutta it says:

64. "When all the Devas headed by Inda (Sakka), and all Brahmas headed by Haritta had come, there came the host of Mara. Lo! The folly of Mara, the Murky One, (Kanha).[15]

Comment: how can it be that the one venerated by so many as supreme godhead, aka lord krishna is also known as evil Mara?

Comment: Mara and Krishna may be completely different persons. Please see [Ghata Jataka](https://www.sacred-texts.com/bud/j4/j4018.htm) for a possible Krishna story.

Comment: Some worshipped Siva instead of Krishna: [Speaking of Siva](https://www.rarebooksocietyofindia.org/book_archive/196174216674_10157052984731675.pdf) has a line of verse, "How can the slaves of the Bodiless God, Desire, know the way our Lord's Men move or the stance of their standing?" The footnote for that says, "The god of love, Kama, once tried to distract Siva's penance. Siva opened his fiery third eye and burned him down. From then on, Love became *anaṅga*, the bodiless or limbless one. Siva's burning down of the god of Desire is the ideal paradigm for all ascetic conquest of temptations."

Comment: sorry , by mistake i down-voted. instead of up-votting.. and I can t change it now.

Comment: There are many maligned statement about other religion in tripitaks. particularly about ajivika, jains and hindus.. I  assume they are added later out of animosity.

Comment: Just because a name like "Krishna" is used, there is no reason to think that this is talking about the same figure. Many of the deities of the Hindus show up in Buddhist literature with names that are different from the popular ones today. For instance, in the Mahāyāna sūtras, Viṣṇu appears as "Nārāyaṇa."

Comment: @Caoimhghin sure whatever...

Comment: @ChrisW yes, shiva is rad...

Comment: ¯\_(ツ)_/¯ "Whatever, whatever," the wood-pecker cries. Still, the bark on the tree's not as soft as the skies...

Comment: From [here](https://www.palikanon.com/english/pali_names/ma/maara.htm): "Māra bears many names in Pāli Literature, chief of them being **Kanha**, Adhipati, Antaka, Namuci and Pamattabandhu." Kanha in Pali literature is Mara, not the Hindu Lord Krishna.

Comment: @ruben2020 that is very interesting...puts the "Padhana Sutta: The Great Struggle"  in a different context...given G.Buddha's history, his state of mind prior to enlightenment, near-death experience, etc...great find..